# Why does css background-size/position not work with shorthand background url?

Tags: html, background, background-position, css

I was working on a slideshow/single page website idea and was at a good stopping point. Since I had the gist of my idea down on a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/FuGH5/13/) I started to clean up my `css`. On each of the 5 tabs they all use the same lines of `css` besides the background image.

This is how I had the css, (working one) [-fiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/FuGH5/13/)

```
#p-home {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Neuschwanstein_Castle_LOC_print.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

#p-about {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Balmoral_Castle.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

This was a little ugly to me so I figured I would clean this up and simplify it like so, [-fiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/FuGH5/16/)

```
#p-home, #p-about, #p-work, #p-contact, #p-blog {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

#p-home {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Neuschwanstein_Castle_LOC_print.jpg") no-repeat;
}

#p-about {
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Balmoral_Castle.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

By using this,

```
#p-home, #p-about, #p-work, #p-contact, #p-blog {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

made the divs ignore those two lines of `css`. I don't see anything wrong with my code and am not 100% sure why that css is not being used When I inspect the console it says it is an invalid property value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `background-image` instead of the shorthand `background` property. Shorthand `background` resets `background-size` and `background-position` to their default values, which is why the first rule ends up not doing anything.

Moving the shared CSS last in the file would also make it work by having last say, although of course this is not a real solution.

Comment: That is very good to know but, did you test this? I just made those changes and it removed the image all together.

Comment: @JoshPowell: No, but I know it to be true. Let me cook up an example.

Comment: Any idea why it removes it all together on my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/FuGH5/17/

Comment: @JoshPowell: Ah yes -- you also have `no-repeat` there at the end (I didn't scroll all the way). Obviously that's not a valid value for `background-image`, if you want to set it then do so with `background-repeat: no-repeat` on the shared rule.

Comment: Ahh I see I see and that did fix it. I am allowed to use `no-repeat` on just `background` right?

Comment: @JoshPowell: Yes, but the way things are you probably won't want to use `background` in this occasion.

Comment: Hmm well thank you so much for that, I was so stumped on this one. I'm going to do some more research on the different background styles since there is more to learn. :] Last question, any ideas why the console was saying it was an invalid property value?

Comment: @JoshPowell: Tip: inspect the element with your browser's developer tools and use the trace styles functionality. It will tell you for each of the background properties where the value comes from, so in this instance it would immediately point to the shorthand resetting them. `url(...) no-repeat` is invalid for `background-image` because the syntax makes no allowance for repeat.

Comment: Thank you for the tip and next time I will do. Never ran into a problem with shared css before so I'm guessing it is not very common for other styles to have this effect.